# Sefer Klal Tora Umitsvot from the Shaagat Arie

Tags: acharonim

See in Shaagat Arie suman 6, he cited his book on principles of Tora and Mitsvot

> ומה שיש לדקדק על דברי הרמב״ם אלו כבר כתבתי באורך רב בספר כלל תורה ומצוות שלי

I never heard of this book. Where can I find it?

Comment: Discussed here: http://simla.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=41464

Comment: Good point my question is already discussed there.is there an answer?

Comment: Yes. It is unpublished.

Comment: חבל על דאבדין
You can write the answer